# Pentaho behind an Apache Server:

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, pentaho, reverse-proxy

I have a Pentaho website on a server, listening on port 8080.

I have, also, an Apache Webserver listening on port 80, and here it is the problem: pentaho should be reachable via the domain pentaho.domain.com, and on one Apache virtualhost is configured like this:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           ServerName pentaho.domain.com
           ServerAlias pentaho

           ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
           ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

   </VirtualHost>
```

If I access via pentaho.domain.com the first time is working without problems (I can login), but after that it redirects to localhost:8080 (which is wrong). What am I missing?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JkMount.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName reports.xx.com
  ServerAlias reports.xx.com
  JkMount /pentaho workeresb
  JkMount /pentaho/* workeresb
  JkMount /pentaho-style workeresb
  JkMount /pentaho-style/* workeresb
</VirtualHost>
```

And in separate file define ajp properties:

```
worker.list=workeresb
worker.workeresb.type=ajp13
worker.workeresb.host=blade2
worker.workeresb.port=8009
worker.workeresb.lbfactor=50
worker.workeresb.cachesize=10
worker.workeresb.cache_timeout=600
worker.workeresb.socket_keepalive=1
worker.workeresb.socket_timeout=300
```